# jquery stop validation only stops after I submit twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validate and I don't want the form to validate when the user closes the form here is my code

```
    var obj = {};
    obj.type = "form";
    obj.formitem = $('#issue_update');
    obj.func = close_dialog
    obj.pdata = {
        func:'save_mention'
    };

    $('.submit').click(function(){
        obj.pdata.submit = $(this).val();
        $('#issue_update').submit();
    });

    $("#issue_update").validate({
        submitHandler: function() {
            run_ajax(obj);
        }
    });
```

and here is the html input

```
    <input type="button" id="close" class="submit cancel" value="Close" />
```

it seems the validation only stops when i push the close button twice

**EDIT**
please note that it only does this when it is in an iframe
**RE-Edit**
actually does the same even stand alone

Comment: Very Strange I changed the order so that validation is setup before the click event and now it works WTF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Strange I changed the order so that validation is setup before the click event and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

one of the demos uses a cancel button:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html

the `resetForm()` method acts to remove validation from the form

```
var validator = $("#form2").validate({
    errorContainer: container,
    errorLabelContainer: $("ol", container),
    wrapper: 'li',
    meta: "validate"
});

$(".cancel").click(function() {
    validator.resetForm();
});
```

Comment: this does in fact reset the form but I still need to click the button again to get it to submit and at that point it just making it so the form is valid